# What is the difference of credential-store and secret-key-credential-store

Tags: ssl, wildfly, elytron

In the following [table](https://docs.wildfly.org/25/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#CredentialStore) the different credential store implementations of different credential types are listed.

| Credential Type | KeyStoreCredentialStore | PropertiesCredentialStore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PasswordCredential | Supported | Unsupported |
| KeyPairCredential | Supported | Unsupported |
| SecretKeyCredential | Supported | Supported |

I still do not quite understand the difference of KeyStoreCredentialStore (credential-store) and PropertiesCredentialStore (secret-key-credential-store) in wildfly subsystem elytron. If KeyStoreCredentialStore supports SecretKeyCredential, why one need PropertiesCredentialStore type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [official documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/25/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#CredentialStore) describe the differences of credential store implementations with details very well. However, for someone starting new with this topic, it can be confusing. Hence, I thought of briefly describing the differences and practical benefits based on my experience:

**KeyStoreCredentialStore** (i.e. credential-store) and **PropertiesCredentialStore** (i.e. secret-key-credential-store) are two default credential store implementations WildFly Elytron contain.

1. *KeyStoreCredentialStore* implementation backed by a *Java KeyStore* which is **protected** using the mechanisms provided by the KeyStore implementations. As listed in table above it supports credential types as *PasswordCredential*, *KeyPairCredential* and *SecretKeyCredential*.
2. *PropertiesCredentialStore* is another implementation dedicated to store *SecretKeyCredential* using a properties file and its primary purpose is to provide an initial key to a server environment. It **does not offer any protection** of the credentials it stores but can be still from filesystem level its access restricted to just the application server process.

In my case I needed e.g. *SecretKeyCredential* to encrypt expression (i.e. passwords in clear text) in server configuration file and I added my *SecretKey* to *KeyStoreCredentialStore* protected by password, rather than using *PropertiesCredentialStore*.